# C# Issue finding controls inside of nested Accordions

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a user control comprised of two nested accordions with a repeater inside, all of which are pulled from a database. The repeater has CheckBoxes with MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxExtenders inside. When the page posts back I am attempting to use LINQ along with a recursive FindControl function to gather all of the CheckBoxes. The issue is that the CheckBoxes are not being located.

Basic Structure, cleaned up for brevity:

```
<ajaxToolkit:Accordion ID="acc1">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <ajaxToolkit:Accordion ID="acc2">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Repeater ID="r1">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cb1" />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cb2" />
                        <ajaxToolkit:MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxExtender ID="mece1" TargetControlID="cb1" />
                        <ajaxToolkit:MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxExtender ID="meceMine2" TargetControlID="cb2" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:Accordion>
    </ContentTemplate>
</ajaxToolkit:Accordion>
```

Everything displays correctly. On button click, elsewhere on the page, I am attempting to gather all of the controls and only the accordion controls, some literals, and the hidden fields I am using are being displayed.

Here is the recursive FindControls function I am using:

```
public static void FindControls(Control start, List<Control> list)
{
    list.Add(start);

    foreach (Control c in start.Controls)
    {
        FindControls(c, list);
    }
}
```

This function is never finding the CheckBoxes in order to return them even though it displays correctly.

Comment: From your example, it looks like you're missing `runat="server"` on your controls.

Comment: @PCasagrande I had run into the problem too. But later found you have to enumerate the Accordian pane with Foreach loop and check if the control exists. Not the intensive way up Control Hierarchy like you coded now

Comment: @ CAbbott I stripped out everything from the example that shouldn't be relevant. Runat code, event triggers used to databind and css classes included. So that isn't the problem.

Comment: At this point I have taken all of the accordions out and replaced them with repeaters. The code worked with only minor changes; mostly type coercion changes to repeaters instead of accordions. I will use jQuery to create the client side functionality I want. I still would love to know why this didn't work though.

Comment: Do you find the acc2 accordian control in your list of found controls? If so check the value of the ChildControlsCreated property. I assume this value is set to false. If that's the case I also asume you have your databinding of the outer accordion (acc1) inside a if(!Postback) condition. I that case I noticed that all nested accordions have the ChildControlsCreated property set to false. I don't why this is, yet. If your remove the if(!Postback) condition the child controls of the nested accordions are created properly and you will find the controls you want. I have to dive in deeper 4m info.

Comment: All of the databinding is being done during the parent control's ItemDataBound.